# How to add user to a group on command line?

Tags: command-line, group, user-account

With Linux/Unix, I can use `useradd -G developers vivek` to add vivek to the developer group. How can I do the same thing with Mac OS X?

Then, how do I check if vivek is in developers group?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can user accounts be managed via the command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/can-user-accounts-be-managed-via-the-command-line)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate.  The linked "duplicate" is about creating a user.  *This* question is about managing the groups an existing user has.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've used this one-liner:

```
sudo dscl localhost -append /Local/Default/Groups/thegroupname GroupMembership theusername
```

Answer (score 32):

To add a user to a group:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -a vivek -t user developers
```

(Note: you can also do this with `dscl` as in @hobs' answer, but you really should both add the user's short name to the GroupMembership list, and also add the user's GeneratedUID to the GroupMembers list.  `dseditgroup` does both with a single operation.)

To check membership:

```
dseditgroup -o checkmember -m vivek developers
```

Or:

```
dsmemberutil checkmembership -U vivek -G developers
```

To remove a user from a group:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -d vivek -t user developers
```

(Again, you can do this with `dscl`, but need to remove the user from both GroupMembership and GroupMembers.  `dseditgroup` does both.)

Comment: Confirmed. dscl only adds without checking user is in group already. it just adds. & it may create duplicate membership for the same user on group.

Comment: Ok this is frustrating. When I try to use the first command it says "Username and password must be provided".  When I use "-u michael" the man page says it should prompt me for a password, but it instead prints the previous message again!

Comment: @Michael if you specify an admin user with `-u`, it should prompt for the password. What version of OS X are you using? Also, try with `sudo` (i.e. `sudo dseditgroup -o ...`) and that should work.

Comment: `dseditgroup -o edit -a vivek -t user developers` is the key. Lot of people suggest `dseditgroup -o edit -a vivek -t developers` but only `dseditgroup -o edit -a vivek -t user developers` is worked

Answer (score 8):

Two ways:
[From the terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/)

> Everything here should be done on the
>   command line 
>   First start dscl like this:
>
> $ dscl localhost
>
> Then cd to the Groups node:
>
> cd /Local/Default/Groups
>
> You can see all the groups using ls.
>   Once you have found the group you are
>   interested in, you can view all its
>   properties with cat groupname. When
>   you are ready to add a user (username)
>   to the group (groupname), use the
>   following command:
>
> append groupname GroupMembership
>   username
>
> If you want to remove a member from a
>   group, use the following command (be
>   careful!):
>
> delete groupname GroupMembership
>   username
>
> When you are finished with your
>   changes, exit dscl by typing exit.

[And the apple official way:](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/11626.html)

> Choose Apple menu > System
>   Preferences, and then click Accounts.
>   Open Accounts preferences Step 2
>
> If the preferences pane is locked,
>   click the lock icon and enter an
>   administrator name and password. Step
>   3
>
> Click the Add (+) button, located
>   below the list of accounts, to create
>   a new account. Step 4
>
> Select a Group from the New Account
>   pop-up menu. Step 5
>
> Enter a name for the group, and then
>   click Create Group. Step 6
>
> Select the checkboxes by the accounts
>   to be members in the group.