# How to create a 'Sharing Only' account via terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm attempting to create a 'Sharing Only' account in an OS X app.

I've tried code based on examples like these:
[Can user accounts be managed via the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/can-user-accounts-be-managed-via-the-command-line)
[What steps are needed to create a new user from the command line on mountain lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82472/what-steps-are-needed-to-create-a-new-user-from-the-command-line-on-mountain-lio)
without success.

From System Preferences -> Users and Groups -> Advanced Options for 'Sharing Only' account:
Home directory: /dev/null
Since /dev/null discards streams directed to it, substitution in place of '/Users/NewUser' into above code doesn't work.

Comment: `/dev/null` is a character pseudo device, not a directory.

Comment: OK. The two links started with something like: dscl / -create /Users/NewUser so I thought this might help; perhaps not. Should I remove the information about /dev/null and replace with: I would like to do the same as this in OS X: Users and Groups -> Add a user account -> New Account = Sharing Only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [bispymusic's answer to a previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82472/what-steps-are-needed-to-create-a-new-user-from-the-command-line-on-mountain-lio/84039#84039):

```
#!/bin/sh

dscl . create /Users/sharinguser    # use whatever account name you want
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser RealName "Sharing-only Account"
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser hint "Password Hint"
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser picture "/Path/To/Picture.png"
dscl . passwd /Users/sharinguser thisistheaccountpassword
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser UniqueID 550    # Pick something unique
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser PrimaryGroupID 20    # Staff group
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser UserShell /usr/bin/false    # No shell access allowed!
dscl . create /Users/sharinguser NFSHomeDirectory /dev/null    # No home directory!
```

As with the script it's based on, you'll either need to run it with `sudo`, or prefix each `dscl` command with `sudo`. Be sure to adjust the account name, RealName, password, and UniqueID (and probably the hint and picture). Note that the critical attributes to make this a sharing-only account are the UserShell and NFSHomeDirectory attributes -- leave these as I have them.

It's a bit confusing that all of the lines refer to /Users/sharinguser (or whatever account name you choose) despite this not existing in the filesystem -- this is because it doesn't refer to a file path, but to the path to a record in OS X's directory service. The filesystem and OS X directory services both use the same path notation, but actually have very little to do with each other. Thus, the home directory path can be set to /dev/null while the account's path directory service stays normal.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Your solution worked and your description is clear. You were correct about me misinterpreting paths. I will seek information on OS X's directory service to gain understanding.

Comment: @wyltowyn if you want to get familiar with the directory service node structure, run `dscl` without any arguments. It'll put you in an interactive mode where you can explore the directory service system very much like you'd explore the filesystem. You can use `cd` to move between "directories", `ls` to list subdirectories and records, and `read` to list the attributes of a record (analogous to `cat` or `more` in the regular shell). When you're done exploring, `exit` will get you out. Hint: start with `cd /Local/Default`, then explore from there.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon! I ran dscl and found a lot of "directories" and records. I can now see the connection between commands I've been using such as 'sharing' and 'dscl' and the directory service.