# How to add a user from the command line in macOS?

Tags: terminal, user-account

In Terminal, I used, `useradd liao2`, as I would also do in Linux, but it failed:

```
useradd liao2
-bash useradd: command not found
```

I also tried using `sudo`:

```
sudo useradd liao2
Password:
sudo: useradd: command not found
```

**How can a user be added from Terminal?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: A better explanation of what I answered can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/4981/118026). Please use that information instead.

ORIGINAL: macOS doesn't have the same unix commands as Linux. To add a user, properly use the system preferences pane for Users & Groups.

System Preferences will have a Users & Groups section. There you can click the + icon in the bottom left to add a user as standard or administrator.

macOS uses a directory service to administrate users. The `adduser` command equivalent for Mac is:

```sh
dscl . -create /Users/USERNAME_HERE
```

You may need admin privledges, therefore `sudo` will be needed like so

```sh
sudo dscl . -create /Users/USERNAME_HERE
```

Followed by a long chain of commands to set up that user properly. Please see the manual page for more detailed information.

Comment: surely it doesn't mean that there is a command for adding user?

Comment: This is an excellent resource: https://blog.travismclarke.com/post/osx-cli-user-management/

Comment: It says invalid path

Comment: @IceFire answer has outdated info. In newer macOS versions, you have to do this instead: `sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Users/USERNAME_HERE`

Comment: Thank you. I’ll update my answer to reflect that after I confirm it. Have any sources?

Comment: @SimonKissane either way with users command executed right after this 'creation', doesn't show "new" user was really created, so it is not actually

Comment: @Павел `users` command only shows currently logged-in users. If you create a user with `dscl localhost -create`, it won't show up in `users` until you log in as that user. That doesn't mean the user isn't created. A better test is calling `id` on the user you created. Which actually does work, provided you set the required attributes on the node (UniqueID, PrimaryGroupID, NFSHomeDirectory, UserShell)

Answer (score 31):

A similar tool to `useradd` is `/usr/sbin/sysadminctl` on macOS . There isn't a manual but `/usr/sbin/sysadminctl -h` is explanatory. You should be aware that the command and options will be stored in your shell's history. Note the last line of the help output so that the user password is not stored in your shell's history.

Comment: sudo sysadminctl -addUser username

Comment: `sudo sysadminctl -addUser xxx -password xxxxxxxx interactive` worked for me on MacOS 13.0