# Delete own user from Mac OS

Tags: bash, script

I was wondering if it is possible to delete my one and only user account because I am creating a script to add and remove users on my Mac.

I have this command here:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/ali"
```

I'm a little bit worried to test that because I don't want to delete my only user with all my files so is it possible?

Comment: You can try to add a new user and test with it, like that if your script works like it should, you'll keep all your data

Comment: For what it's worth, if you run the script with `sudo`, you are effectively running it as `root`, so whatever safeguards might be present for the current user, these won't work in this case, because the current user is actually a different one.

Comment: Adding and removing users on the mac via command-line interface is not a great idea and I don't advise trying to do so. Please see my answered question here for a bit more info. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286749/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-command-line-in-macos/286750#286750

Comment: @klanomath thank you for fixing my link. I commented it because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: As long as you have a backup and/or don’t delete the user files, you can always boot to single user mode, remove the /var/db/.AppleSetupDone file and then restart. The setup assistant will let you set up a new admin account and then you can re-create the missing accounts, reusing the old home folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/ali"` will remove the user *ali*  from the local Directory Services database.

After login out you won't be able to login with user *ali* again. The user folder of *ali* **won't** be deleted.

To delete the folder /Users/ali and its content an additional command is necessary.

---

The user *ali* can be recreated though by booting to single user mode and using the [remove .AppleSetupDone file trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac) in a two-stage process.

1. Create a new admin with a different name than ali (e.g. *ali2*)
2. After the configuration is done create a new admin with a different name than ali (e.g. ali3)
3. Logout as *ali2* and login as *ali3*
4. Modify *ali2* (e.g. name/user directory/user id etc.) with Users & Groups PrefPane/Directory Utility.app/command line to restore the previous entries of *ali*.

**This won't work if your main volume is encrypted with FileVault2!**

---

**It's absolutely not recommended to test user creation/deletion scripts like this on your production Mac. Download VirtualBox, create a virtual machine running macOS and test your scripts inside there.**