Locations outside /Users where macOS writes user files?
After a clean install of Sequoia (15.2) I am adding my user accounts. Due to other systems on my home network (and wanting to use NFS) I want to use specific UID's for the new accounts. This is a supported option on OSX - just create the account, then choose advanced and it is possible to set the UID's that I want to use.
The problem is that the action of creating the account creates the home directory (/Users/xyz) using the initial UID (501, 502, 503, ...). I realize that I could just chown the files however due to SIP, I don't trust that that will work correctly. Instead my procedure is that:

After creating the accounts.
I reboot into recovery mode (to prevent SIP getting in the way).
Open a terminal
Execute rm -rf /Users/user1 /Users/user2 ....
Reboot
Log in as each user to recreate the home directories with the correct file ownerships.

I realize that that is a convoluted process, however it seems to work / works for me.
My question is: Are there any other locations where OSX writes user specific files outsize of /Users during user account creation?
I ask because, I know other unix systems sometimes write files for things like crontabs, mail queues, lock files, etc and I want to check to make sure I have the correct ownership on all such files.

Wouldn‘t something like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/can-user-accounts-be-managed-via-the-command-line be the better way?

The short answer is no, Apple user management is an area I have played in in the past (Running OSX Server domain and doing custom integrations), it's super Apple specific and non-documented, read: Its a can of worms that I do not wish to re-open. That article is old and given my knowledge of the area, I have 0 trust in the answer.

Even without manual creation, changing the UID in Settings and doing chown -r /Users/foo should be enough. There is no SIP in user directories.
